# How to resolve server error in Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am creating a web application, using socket.io . A Server error occurred while connecting to the server. We found out that the error is in the backend. What could be written incorrectly here? Code:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const fs = require("fs");
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('path').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('path').toString();

const http = require('https').Server({key:privateKey,cert:certificate}, app);

const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const port = 9998;
const debug = true;
var connectedArray = new Array()
const delay = 60 * 1000

const mysql = require('mysql2');
const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'user_name',
    password: 'user_password',
    database: 'database',
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    socket.on('register', msg => {
        console.log("User registered")
        connectedArray.push({
            connectmessage: msg,
            socket: socket,
        })
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        if (debug) console.log('User disconnected')
    })

})
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./index.html')
})
            
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started listening on port ${port}...`)
})
```

P.S: The problem began to arise after binding the domain
P.S 2: I have two sites on server, on different Apache virtual hosts
P.S 3: I am using https

Comment: can you add the exact error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `Error: server error at a.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at s.T.emit (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at s.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at s.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at o.T.emit (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at o.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at o.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6) at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)`